# How to type the index and style props passed to Row function using React-Window

Tags: typescript, react-window

I am trying to type the following two parameters passed to Row function.

```
//https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

const StyledSection = styled.section`
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #C0C0C0;
`;

const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
  <div className={index % 2 ? 'ListItemOdd' : 'ListItemEven'} style={style}>
    Row {index}
  </div>
);

const Scroller = () => {
  return (
    <StyledSection>
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => {
          return (
            <List height={height} width={width} itemSize={20} itemCount={300}>
              {Row}
            </List>
          );
        }}
      </AutoSizer>
    </StyledSection>
  );
};

export { Scroller };
```

So the following snippet of code typescript infers the index and style parameters as type any. I tried to  inline the type for index as number but then the compiler says index is not defined.

```
   const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
      <div className={index % 2 ? 'ListItemOdd' : 'ListItemEven'} style={style}>
        Row {index}
      </div>
    );
```

Any ideas how to provide types to these two paramaters. react-window has its own d.ts file. Here is the working codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/infinite-scroller-52b7d?file=/src/Scroller.tsx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you seek for?

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';

const Row = ({ index, style }: { index: number; style: CSSProperties; }) => (
  <div className={index % 2 ? 'ListItemOdd' : 'ListItemEven'} style={style}>
    Row {index}
  </div>
);
```

You can still add typing when using object destructuring. Also you can use your IDE to find the type of `style`, using `goto declaration` on the first `style` of `style={style}`. (ctrl-b or ctrl-q in jetbrain IDE, doesn't know for VScode, sorry).

Comment: yes, yes, yes. Thank you. I was trying to type inside of the destructured props object, so inside the { index: number, style}. thanks again and for the CSSProperties and tooling tip. Merci!

Comment: Why add a custom type/interface when you have a well-maintained types library `@types/react-window`? Please check my answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74191187/6335249.

Comment: @sohammondal Indeed if there is some typing available, best is to use it. In his case he was also incorrectly typing a destructured object.

Answer (score 3):

There's a better way of adding type to the `List` child component as all the types are already available in the `@types/react-window` package. You can find them [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-window/index.d.ts).

For your case, it is pretty simple -

1. First install `@types/react-window` as a dev dependency.
2. Import the `ListChildComponentProps` type form the above-installed package.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ListChildComponentProps } from 'react-window'

const Row: React.FC<ListChildComponentProps> = ({ index, style }) => (
  <div className={index % 2 ? 'ListItemOdd' : 'ListItemEven'} style={style}>
    Row {index}
  </div>
);
```

**Advanced usage**

If you want the `data` prop to be properly typed, you can pass custom type/interface to the `ListChildComponentProps`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ListChildComponentProps } from 'react-window'

interface Person {
  name: string
  email: string
}

const Row: React.FC<ListChildComponentProps<Person[]>> = ({ index, style, data }) => (
  <div style={style}>
    {data[index].name} - {data[index].email}
  </div>
);
```